# Content Type not being set in cURL in PHP

Tags: php, http, curl, header, content-type

I'm trying to send a request to an API (Xero, to be specific) using cURL but I was apparently sending empty requests. I checked the cURL info and it looks like I don't have a Content-Type set, even though I've been setting it in the code.

Here's my code:

```
    $content = $this->getContent();
    $headers = [
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Content-Length: " . strlen($content),
        "Connection: close"
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->getUrl());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

    de($headers, curl_getinfo($ch));
```

`de()` is a a "dump and exit" function, and it outputs this:

```
 array(3) {
  [0] =>
      string(47) "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  [1] =>
      string(20) "Content-Length: 1003"
  [2] =>
      string(17) "Connection: close"
}

array(26) {
  'url' =>
  string(41) "https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices"
  'content_type' =>
  NULL
  'http_code' =>
  int(0)
  'header_size' =>
  int(0)
  'request_size' =>
  int(0)
  'filetime' =>
  int(0)
  'ssl_verify_result' =>
  int(0)
  'redirect_count' =>
  int(0)
  'total_time' =>
  double(0)
  'namelookup_time' =>
  double(0)
  'connect_time' =>
  double(0)
  'pretransfer_time' =>
  double(0)
  'size_upload' =>
  double(0)
  'size_download' =>
  double(0)
  'speed_download' =>
  double(0)
  'speed_upload' =>
  double(0)
  'download_content_length' =>
  double(-1)
  'upload_content_length' =>
  double(-1)
  'starttransfer_time' =>
  double(0)
  'redirect_time' =>
  double(0)
  'certinfo' =>
  array(0) {
    }
  'primary_ip' =>
  string(0) ""
  'primary_port' =>
  int(0)
  'local_ip' =>
  string(0) ""
  'local_port' =>
  int(0)
  'redirect_url' =>
  string(0) ""
}
```

As far as I can see I am setting the headers correctly (the constant is spelled correctly and I haven't set them multiple times). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should transfer something before to call curl_getinfo

Comment: Ah yeah, my bad. Looks like the issue is something else :(

Answer (score 2):

First check with `curl_error` function [click me for detail!!](https://www.php.net/curl_error)

since your url is `https`. so ssl verifying process is followed.

Informal fix:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Formal fix:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/CAcerts/your_certificate.crt");
```

Where is certificate?

1. Browse url in firefox browser

[image: Go to the site]

2. Click lock pad at left of address bar
3. Then click more information
   [image: more info]
4. Now click the `view certificate` button
   [image: certificate]
5. In opened pop up you will see two tab in that click details tab (shortcut `ALT + D`).
6. Then click export button and save the certificate

[image: export]

7. That is the path you have to give here

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/CAcerts/your_certificate.crt")