# PHP curl exec failing on good url

Tags: php, curl

I have made other calls using curl but they were to a different site, this is the url: https://api.eveonline.com/account/APIKeyInfo.xml.aspx?keyID=5710518&vCode=qIav0wxj9V8T7AJmKn58FWLW6x55un06pT8sRFljnBFagvbuwbX2cSWLoO4gkjvS

and the code which I believe is correct is

```
            $service_url = 'https://api.eveonline.com/account/APIKeyInfo.xml.aspx?keyID=5710518&vCode=qIav0wxj9V8T7AJmKn58FWLW6x55un06pT8sRFljnBFagvbuwbX2cSWLoO4gkjvS';
            $curl = curl_init( $service_url );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
            $curl_response = curl_exec( $curl );
            if ( $curl_response === false ) {
                $info = curl_getinfo( $curl );
                curl_close( $curl );
                die( 'error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export( $info ) );
            }
            curl_close( $curl );
            $xml = simplexml_load_string( $curl_response );
            print_r($xml);
```

All the eror information says is that there was an error during curl exec. There is no additional information and nothing I was able to find on google help

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: seriously... http://imgur.com/a/MXiek that's a picture of the error I get

Comment: Notice the `content_type` is `null`? This will help you since the URL is https: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733765/content-type-not-being-set-in-curl-in-php

Comment: Output for me:
http://imgur.com/a/mouit

Formatted output: http://imgur.com/a/8vW86

Comment: Thank you that did help, how is it working for everyone else if your not changing anything?

Comment: I changed nothing on the code, only put the code between"<pre>" HTML tags.

Comment: Works here either. Use `curl_error` to get more information, then show us.